# What is the behaviour when we assign constant integer reference to a integer pointer in c++?

Tags: c++

Please look into the below code. I assigned an address of a const integer value to an integer pointer. And i can able to print those addresses also, but i am not able to print the values(commented lines). Could anybody please explain what is actually happening here internally?

```
 int main()
  {
       int *a;
       cout<<a<<"\n";
       a = (int*)20;
       cout<<a<<"\n";
       cout<<(int*)20<<"\n";
       int *b;
       cout<<b<<"\n";
       b = (int*)20;
       cout<<b<<"\n";
       //cout<<*a<<"\n";
       //cout<<*b<<"\n";
       return 0;
}


Output:
-------
0
0x14
0x14
0x7fff3c914690
0x14
```

Comment: Don't use C-style casts. You would have to use `reinterpret_cast` to make this work. This is a clue that 90% chance you are doing something dangerous!

Answer (score 4):

You didn't assign the address of a const integer value. Instead what you said was, "Treat 20 as an address" i.e. `(int*)20`. So when you dereferenced it (i.e. `*a`) you were saying what is at address 20 which of course is garbage. You need to store 20 somewhere before getting the address of it.

```
const int value = 20;
const int * a = &value;
cout << *a << endl;
```

Would be fine...

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through that line by line:

```
int *a;
```

This initializes a pointer to int with random data that happened to be in memory at the time.

```
cout<<a<<"\n";
```

Prints the memory address `a` holds, which is random because it wasn't initialized.

```
a = (int*)20;
```

Treats `20` as a memory address containing an int, and makes `a` point to that memory address (which again contains random junk data).

```
cout<<a<<"\n";
```

Outputs the address that `a` holds, which is `20`.

```
cout<<(int*)20<<"\n";
```

Outputs `20` as a memory address.

```
int *b;
cout<<b<<"\n";
b = (int*)20;
cout<<b<<"\n";
```

Same as with `a`, see above.

```
cout<<*a<<"\n";
cout<<*b<<"\n";
```

These two would dereference the memory at address `20` which will result in undefined behavior.

In conclusion, this code doesn't make much sense.